# Flash Firefox OS on "unsupported" device

Tags: android, tablet, smartphone, firmware, firefox-os

I'm developing some apps for Firefox OS, but am currently limited to doing so on the *Firefox OS Simulator*. I'd like to flash Firefox OS onto a real device, but I own none of the supported devices, and of some of them I can't even find a single mention anywhere on the internet with the exception of the wiki.

Now I have this very slow *Cherry Mobility* Android JB (originally ICS) tablet lying around. Would there be any chance of getting Firefox OS running *properly* on this device, or is it a lost case?

Comment: I'd say there is a remote chance, but at a severe risk that things won't go swimmingly.
If the device isn't listed as supported, chances are it will contain hardware for which there are no proper Firefox OS drivers yet.
Your mileage may vary.
(by which i mean anywhere from "runs like a charm" to "crashes and burns when i look in its general direction")

Comment: *running*?, maybe. *properly*? almost definitely not.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not really a programming question IMHO.

Comment: @CommonsWare It is development related.

Comment: @TimothyGroote As Firefox OS has Android's core, I thouht maybe I could extract the drivers from Android, somehow, and use them with Firefox OS?

Comment: "It is development related" -- so is formatting a hard drive, and that too would be off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't see how it is.

Comment: @RobinJ Firefox OS is based on android? where did you get this information?

Comment: @TimothyGroote it actually is, as it uses the Android kernel and driver stack, mostly due to compatibility reasons (so device vendors don't have to port their driver stack for Firefox OS, if they have an android device driver stack, they are (more or less) good to go).

Comment: @SzmozsánszkyIstván Exactly. That's why I thought maybe there was a way to extract he drivers from the Android ROM and use them with Firefox OS.

Comment: +1 on this, but I guess this question is better off in the Android stackexchange:

http://android.stackexchange.com/

See this similar: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62339/firefox-os-galaxy-nexus-gt-i9250-boot-fail-after-flashing

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended if you cannot solve hardware related (gonk porting) issues.

Every device has its own hardware combination and they need different configuration (what B2G `configure.sh` command does) to make everything works.

Here's the supported device list
https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G/blob/master/config.sh

Comment: It's not exactly true. The devices marked in the config.sh aren't all the supported devices for FirefoxOS. They are the only the devices supported by the builder. As an example, some devices running on Android have a copycat with FirefoxOS. Technically flashing a rom of firefoxOS might work without big issues on these devices. For example Alcatel 6015x and Alcatel 6014x. But the 6015x doesn't have a custom rom available in `config.sh` yet.